# How do you delete or rename content parts in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

I gave a content part a wrong name and I want to rename it. I tried renaming the classes and all calls of it in the solution to no avail. I even tried deleting entries from the ShellFeatures table and the table generated by Migrations itself, but that just made things worse. Now the whole module's features aren't being recognized. Anyone tried this before?

Comment: Does it work if you clear your App_Data folder, and start up a new site?

Comment: I'm hesitating to clear App_Data folder. Then I'd have to start over my site from scratch. I've got most of it set up and stuff

Comment: You could always just cut and paste it somewhere.  Just to see if it works.  Then maybe use Import/Export module to pull data into the new install.  Just something to try I guess.

Comment: If you keep the Sites\DefaultSite\SiteSettings.txt file you will not have to re-setup your site, though deleting everything else from the App_data folder is a way to clear cached settings and have your parts remapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I just had to tackle this and this is the first result I landed on from Google.

You can delete the `ContentPart` and add it again using migrations for example:

```
    public int UpdateFrom3() {
        // remove the AccreditationsPart part cleanly
        ContentDefinitionManager.DeletePartDefinition(typeof (AccreditationsPart).Name);
enter code here
        // re-add the AccreditationsPart again
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(typeof (AccreditationsPart).Name,
            cfg = > cfg
            .Attachable()
            .WithDescription("Adds a row of configurable accreditations to the content type"));
        return 4;
    }
```

You would need to customise the update numbers to fit your current `migrations.cs` and also change the `AlterPartDefinition` to match whatever you want it to be.

**WARNING:** This is only intended for fixing problems that you catch straight away. When you delete the part in the first section of the migration you will lose any associated data. If you already have the code running in production then you will have to use a different approach.

Comment: The DeletePartDefinition before AlterPartDefinition seems to do the trick for me, but wouldn't that delete any existing data in a production site?

Comment: Yes you're correct. I was only thinking about a scenario where you catch it straight away because your module isn't working. I should point this out in my main answer.